# Codeception - how to run phpunit test from Drupal core in codeception?

Tags: drupal-8, codeception

There are PHPUnit tests in core Drupal 8. I'm currently running them with phpunit command but I use Codeception on the project so I would like to run all tests in one tool and have one report. Is it possible and if so, what is the best practice?

Comment: If all unit tests are in one place, you could move them to tests/unit/ directory.

Comment: move everything loses meaning because they are together with the modules so that I would have to move them with all files or add dependencies in every test which is pointless because they are delivered to Drupal modules by their creators